# Is there an analogue of put function of Map interface in List?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have an ArrayList(*input*) of Node objects. Each node stores the information about how many times a sentence has been searched. The definition of Node class is -

```
class Node {
    String sentence;
    int count;

    Node(String st, int t) {
        sentence = st;
        count = t;
    }
}
```

the attribute *sentence* stores the sentence and *count* the number of times it was searched.
Now I am given a sentence and I want to add it to this list with the updated count. The problem is the sentence may already be present in the list, in which case I just have to update the count attribute of that particular node by +1. In map interface it is easy by using -

```
map.put(sentence, map.getOrDefault(sentence, 0) + 1);
```

But how can I do it in List?

Comment: Why are you using a `List` in the first place? As you have realised, you should use a `Map`. This is why `Map` exists.

Comment: you need to search

Comment: Use [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: Please explain if List has duplicate Node (ie of same sentence). what should be the behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you I like to go object-oriented. A `Map<String, Integer>` isn’t satisfactory. We want to use your `Node` class.

I think that what you want is a `Map<String, Node>`. With it you can look up the node from the sentence. You may fit your `Node` class with a method to increment the count. And use `computeIfAbsent()` to create new nodes as necessary.

```
    Map<String, Node> map = new HashMap<>();
    
    map.computeIfAbsent("Cat", s -> new Node(s, 0)).incrementCount();
    map.computeIfAbsent("House", s -> new Node(s, 0)).incrementCount();
    map.computeIfAbsent("Cat", s -> new Node(s, 0)).incrementCount();
    
    System.out.println(map.values());
```

With a simple `toString` method in your class the output is:

> [Cat: 2, House: 1]

I would also find it perfectly meaningful if your constructor takes only one argument, the sentence, and always sets `count` to 0. Or you may have both constructors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter the list , using Java 8 streams.

```
list.stream().filter(node->node.sentence.equals(sentenceToSearch)).findFirst()
```

Entire code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Optional;

class Node {
    String sentence;
    int count;

    Node(String st, int t) {
        sentence = st;
        count = t;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node{" +
                "sentence='" + sentence + '\'' +
                ", count=" + count +
                '}';
    }
}
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ArrayList<Node> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Node("Hello world",3));
        list.add(new Node("Hello java",2));
        list.add(new Node("I am Ironman",3000));
        updateCount("Hello world",list,4);
        updateCount("Hello sam",list,5);
        list.forEach(System.out::println);

    }

    static void  updateCount(String sentenceToSearch,ArrayList<Node> list,int updateCount){
        Optional<Node> optNode = list.stream().filter(node->node.sentence.equals(sentenceToSearch)).findFirst();

        if(optNode.isPresent()){
            Node node=optNode.get();
            node.count++;
        }else{
            list.add(new Node(sentenceToSearch,updateCount));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: if not found, he wants to use the updated count value instead of 1

Comment: @Ajeetkumar — or she (I don’t know which)

Comment: haha, looks like he cuz name Sparsh suggest it's a boy, Congratulation :)

Comment: Thanks, learnt something new today, @Ajeetkumar. See if I can remember next time.

Answer (score 0):

- if found -> increase the count by 1
- if not -> use the updated count
- consider adding toString() method in your Node class

```
public class NodeTester {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     List<Node> list = new ArrayList<>();

     String sentence = "abc";
     int updatedCount = 6;

     list.add(new Node("abc", 2));
     Optional<Node> nodeSearched = list.stream().filter(n -> n.sentence.equals(sentence)).findAny();

     if (nodeSearched.isPresent()) {
         Node node = nodeSearched.get();
         node.count = node.count + 1;
     } else { // not found
         list.add(new Node(sentence, updatedCount));
     }

     System.out.println("Result " + list);

 }
}
```

Comment: Starting from Java 9 you may replace your if-else construct with a call to `nodeSearched.ifPresentOrElse()` (which I find more elegant).

Comment: oh, sorry, gave a thought, edited the answer